# iOS11 save and see .txt file in Files app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, files-app

I am trying to save the string in `.txt` file and wants to see that `.txt` file in Files app. It is possible to save and read the file in documents directory but I am struggling to save and see in Files app.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the file with:

```
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fileName = @"file.txt";
NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```

And read it with:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = @"file.txt";
NSString *pathDocuments = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

After having the file path then it is up to you to parse it.

Comment: Hi, here question is asked about to read and write .txt file into Files app which is in iOS 11. You are giving answer for own apps sandbox